# XSD Unique Constraint of elements in different sequences

Tags: xml, xsd, unique

I have follow xsd Schema file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="Config">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Modul">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Content1">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Content2">
                      <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element name="AttributeType1">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                              <xsd:attribute name="X" type="xsd:double" use="required" />
                            </xsd:complexType>
                          </xsd:element>
                          <xsd:element name="AttributeType1">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                              <xsd:attribute name="X" type="xsd:double" use="required" />
                            </xsd:complexType>
                          </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                      </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                </xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:unique name="Content2NameUniqueKey">
                  <xsd:selector xpath="Content2" />
                  <xsd:field xpath="@Name" />
               </xsd:unique>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
           </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:unique name="Content1NameUniqueKey">
            <xsd:selector xpath="Content1" />
            <xsd:field xpath="@Name" />
          </xsd:unique>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xs:schema>
```

With the unique constraints I can check if the content1 name is unique and if all content2 name`s are unuique in a content1 element.

But my problem ist, i want to check if all content2 elements are unique in all content1 elements. Therefore there can only be one content1 element with the name "xy" in the complete XML-File.

Could someone please help me?

Many greetings to all!

Answer (score 1):

The unique element for `Content2` should simply be moved one level higher in `Modul`, with the XPath `Content1/Content2`. That way, `Content2` elements must also be unique through the entire `Modul`.

There is another issue with a double occurrence of `AttributeType1`, which I replaced with a `min/maxOccurs=2`, but it may simply be a typo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="Config">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Modul">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Content1">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Content2">
                      <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element name="AttributeType1" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="2">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                              <xsd:attribute name="X" type="xsd:double" use="required" />
                            </xsd:complexType>
                          </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                      </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:unique name="Content1NameUniqueKey">
            <xsd:selector xpath="Content1" />
            <xsd:field xpath="@Name" />
          </xsd:unique>
          <xsd:unique name="Content2NameUniqueKey">
            <xsd:selector xpath="Content1/Content2" />
            <xsd:field xpath="@Name" />
          </xsd:unique>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: @MrPink: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.